# Mathematica label callout

Tags: plotting, labeling

I wanted to created callout for my plot, the plot is created by:

```
data with na22: https://ufile.io/6gw0s2aq

peaks = {{398, 0.511}, {495, 0.662}, {819, 1.173}, {921, 1.332}};

lm = LinearModelFit[peaks, x, x]

ListPlot[{lm[First[#]], Last[#]} & /@ na22, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, All}, All}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Energy (MeV)", "Counts"}, 
 RotateLabel -> True, Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[{"\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[InvisiblePrefixScriptBase]\), \
\(22\)]\)Na"}, Above]]
```

But after adding callout: `Callout[4680,"Peak",Above]` I get an error:

[image: error]

How label should be created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:** Using your data, the solution is the same: [`Callout`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Callout.html) is a wrapper ("Callout[data, expr, ...] can be used as a wrapper in visualization functions ...") not a [`ListPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html) option.

```
na22 = Import["/Users/roberthanlon/Downloads/na22.txt", "Table"];

peaks = {{398, 0.511}, {495, 0.662}, {819, 1.173}, {921, 1.332}};

lm = LinearModelFit[peaks, x, x];

data = {lm[First[#]], Last[#]} & /@ na22;

maxPt = Select[data, #[[2]] == Max[data[[All, 2]]] &][[1]]

(* {0.51043, 4680} *)

ListPlot[
 data /. maxPt :> Callout[maxPt, "Peak", Above],
 FrameLabel -> {"Energy (MeV)", "Counts"},
 RotateLabel -> True,
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}},
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

**EDIT 2:** For multiple peaks use [`FindPeaks`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindPeaks.html)

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{peaks, n, repl},
  peaks = ReverseSortBy[
    data[[FindPeaks[data[[All, 2]], 4, Automatic, threshold][[All, 
        1]]]], Last];
  n = 1;
  repl = (# -> Callout[#, "Peak " <> ToString[n++], Above] & /@ peaks);
  ListPlot[data /. repl,
   FrameLabel -> {"Energy (MeV)", "Counts"},
   RotateLabel -> True,
   Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}},
   ImageSize -> Large]],
 {{threshold, 2000}, {5, 15, 20, 25} 100,
  ControlType -> SetterBar}]
```

[image]

**EDIT 3:** For arbitrary points with arbitrary labels:

```
Module[{peaks, repl, labels},
 peaks = Select[data, #[[2]] == 4680 || #[[2]] == 507 &];
 labels = {
   StringForm["`` label", Superscript["1", "st"]], 
   StringForm["`` label", Superscript["2", "nd"]]};
 repl = (#[[1]] -> Callout[#[[1]], #[[2]], Above] & /@
    Transpose[{peaks, labels}]);
 ListPlot[data /. repl,
  FrameLabel -> {"Energy (MeV)", "Counts"},
  RotateLabel -> True,
  Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}},
  ImageSize -> Large]]
```

Comment: Is it possible to easy add second "peak" label to another point?

Comment: In the `Manipulate`, set the threshold to `2000` and only the highest two peaks will be labeled. Or extract the `Module` and replace `threshold` in the extracted code with `2000`

Comment: You edited the answer. I just wanted to label two peaks manually from the list without using manipulate, just list: `peaks = {{0.51043, 4680}}, {{1.26648, 507}};`

Comment: Extract the `Module`. In the extracted code replace the definition of `peaks` with your definition of `peaks`

Comment: It works, but how to use own name for each peak?

Comment: Spend some time when formulating questions to clearly specify what you want so that repeated clarifications aren't required.